# send text message to mobile number by free service

Tags: ruby-on-rails

There is any way for send text message to mobile number by any free service.

I have done that by twilio, but I don't want to purchase any thing,

Is there any in-build functionality in rails, to send text message in  phone number like email ?

Comment: No, nothing like this is built in rails.

Answer (score 0):

> There is No build-in functionality in rails for sending text messages.
>
> Instead of that you can use third party services. (msg91, sendgrid,
>   gupshup). In that Per account they will give 100 free sms per month.
>   You can use that service without buying anything.
>
> If you want to send more messages you have to purchase paid services.

.